# Xpath Required for identifying nodes based on a criteria in Selenium.

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

I'm working on a Selenium Project.

I have a HTML File (copied below) for which I have to write a XPath expression in order to find out the value of 6th "b" element under "a" for which:

- 2nd "b" has a value of "888" and
- 4th "666" has a value of "World is Great".

### HTML Code

```
 <a>
    <b>111</b>
    <b>222</b>
    <b>333</b>
    <b>444</b>
    <b>ttt</b>
    <b>uuu</b>
</a>

<a>
    <b>999</b>
    <b>888</b>
    <b>777</b>
    <b>World is Great</b>
    <b>aaa</b>
    <b>bbb</b>
</a>
```

---

I tried the following, but didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

```
//a[b='888'][b='World is Great']/b[6]

//a[contains(@b[2], '888') and contains(@b[4], 'World is Great')]/b[6]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Q.:** (modified) *to find out the value of 6th "b" element under "a" for which - -- 2nd "b" has a value of "888" and -- 4th "b" has a value of "World is Great"*

Try this:

```
"//a[b[2]='888' and b[4] = 'World is Great' ]/b[6]"
```

**Attention**:
But your fist try `//a[b='888'][b='World is Great']/b[6]` should also work. If it does not return "bbb" for your example there is something else wrong.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Actually, you are correct mine first try should have worked, but it did not because of following - 
**<td class="whiteStripe" valign="top" align="left"> 2 </td>**
<b> in actual is <td> as shown above.
But not sure why, "//a[td='2']" is not working. When I'm using gettext() to read the contents of <td> I'm getting "2" but in expression "//a[td='2']" doesn't work.

Couldn't figure out why :-(